# Eclipse Kepler: switching to the Web perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

How can I switch to the Web perspective in Eclipse Kepler, so that i can see the Servers tab in the console? Or is there any other way i can access servers tab in Eclipse Kepler?

Please note that the Web Perspective is not available in Eclipse Kepler. Please  help me with this

Comment: have you install "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" for web perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The `Web` perspective is available in Kepler if you have the `Eclipse Web Developer Tools` installed. Some Eclipse downloads include this, others do not.

If you don't have this installed you can install it in your Eclipse by going to `Help > Install New Software...`. Work with the Eclipse Kepler software site and look in the `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` section.